# Help with fixing proof that transcendental extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in transcendental extension of $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$

Tags: field-theory, model-theory, polynomial-rings

Good morning. I am trying to prove the following statement (I suspect it is true):

Consider a finite set $(a_{1},...,a_{n})$ of elements in an elementary extension $*\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ of $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$. Is $\mathbb{Q}(a_{1},...,a_{n})$ dense in $\mathbb{Q}_{p}(a_{1},...,a_{n})$? (The $a_{1},...,a_{n}$ are transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$).

I attempted the proof as follows:

We can view polynomials from $\mathbb{Q}_{p}(a_{1},...,a_{n})$ as a quotient of two linear combinations of elements from $(a_{1},...,a_{n})$ raised to various powers and with coefficients from $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$. For each term $q_{i}a_{i}^{k}$, i used the fact that every $q_{i}$ in $\mathbb{Q}_{p}(a_{1},...,a_{n})$, if not an element of $\mathbb{Q}(a_{1},...,a_{n})$, is a limit point so there exists a net $(b_{\alpha})_{\alpha}$ in the latter which converges to $q_{i}$. Since $a_{i}^{k}$ is also in $\mathbb{Q}(a_{1},...,a_{n})$, so too is the net $ (b_{\alpha}a_{i}^{k})_{\alpha} \to q_{i}a_{i}^{k}$.

We can do this for every constituent term of the polynomial in the numerator, then form a net by adding the nets used for the individual terms. This net eventually converges to the entire polynomial in the numerator.

I then hoped to repeat this process for the denominator and divide the two nets, which would show that every element of $\mathbb{Q}_{p}(a_{1},...,a_{n})$ is a limit point of a net in $\mathbb{Q}(a_{1},...,a_{n})$, but I am concerned that the denominator of such a net might reach $0$ at some point prior to convergence, and can't think of a way to work around that.

Is there any convenient way to exclude this case, or will I need to revise my entire attempt?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you say "elementary extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$", what language are you working over?

Comment: What is the topology on $\mathbb{Q}_p(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$?

Comment: @EricWofsey The language here is the language for field theory together with a predicate $V$ for the valuation ring and predicates $P_{n}, n=2,3...$ for each $n$-th power. These additional predicates are included for the sake of quantifier elimination.

Comment: @TobErnack Here I would be using the topology induced by the $p$-adic metric i.e. open balls as a basis, in the same way that we use the metric to define a topology on $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ itself. Is that correct?